# How could I split an array of words without using split() in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to split words from a sentence in an array without using split() but using charAt() function.

```
function sentenceToWordArray(sentence) {
    let stringArray = [""]
    let j = 0
    
    for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == " ") {
            j++;
            stringArray.push("")
        
        } else {
            stringArray[j] += sentence.charAt(i)
        }
    }
    return stringArray
}
```

Now I have the code working but I'm encountering some problems like for example "Hello World" turns into "Hello", "World" but if I add extra spaces for example " Hello  World " it outputs ['', 'hello', '', 'there', '']. Is there a way to remove the extra spaces?

Comment: If the extra white spaces are only at the beginning and end of the string, then [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) should do the trick.

Comment: @Geshode The problem are space entries in an array, not in a string.

Comment: for a quick fix you can just filter the resulting array `return stringArray.filter(x => x)`

Comment: Well, OP said, that "Hello World" worked correctly, but " Hello World " didn't. So, I assumed, OP meant the extra white spaces in the beginning and end of the string were causing the problem. So, removing those with trim and then running the trimmed string through the loop, seemed to me like a way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method, which trims the whitespaces from the start and end of a `string`

```js
function sentenceToWordArray(sentence) {
    let stringArray = [""]
    let j = 0
    const trimedSentence = sentence.trim()
    for (let i = 0; i < trimedSentence.length; i++) {
        if (trimedSentence.charAt(i) == " ") {
            j++;
            stringArray.push("")
        
        } else {
            stringArray[j] += trimedSentence.charAt(i)
        }
    }
    return stringArray
}

console.log(sentenceToWordArray('Hello, World'));
console.log(sentenceToWordArray('  Hello, World'));
console.log(sentenceToWordArray('Hello, World  '));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find all words in an input sentence, you may use `match()` and avoid splitting altogether:

```js
var input = " Hello World ";
var words = input.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quickfix:

```js
function sentenceToWordArray(sentence) {
    let stringArray = [""]
    let j = 0
    
    for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == " ") {
            j++;
            stringArray.push("")
        
        } else {
            stringArray[j] += sentence.charAt(i)
        }
    }
    return stringArray.filter(w => w.length > 0) // <-- I added this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need something called a "state machine" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Basically, you have a set of states your function is in. With each new input (=character), depending on the current state, the state is changed into another one, and some actions are performed as a side effect.

Example:

```js
const STATE_BEGIN = 1   // no last character
const STATE_SPACE = 2   // the last character was a space
const STATE_NOSPACE = 3 // the last character was not a space

function split(text) {
    let state = STATE_BEGIN
    let words = []

    for (let char of text) {

        let isSpace = char === ' '

        switch (state) {
            case STATE_BEGIN:
            case STATE_SPACE:
                if (!isSpace) {
                    words.push(char)
                    state = STATE_NOSPACE
                } else {
                    state = STATE_SPACE
                }
                break;
            case STATE_NOSPACE:
                if (!isSpace) {
                    words[words.length - 1] += char
                    state = STATE_NOSPACE
                } else {
                    state = STATE_SPACE
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return words;
}

//

text = `       How razorback-jumping frogs     can level six piqued     gymnasts!`

console.log(split(text))
```